# jfx:build-jar working fine jfx:native some functions does not work, how to debug exe?

Tags: javafx, jar, exe

Im building app with javafx based on: **zulu8.38.0.13-ca-fx-jdk8.0.212-win_x64**

When i build jfx:native and run program from exe file some functions does not work and app crashing.

When i just run it by jar and command pompt everything is fine.

How can i debug exe file to detect error?

i found log file in runtime folder:

> Current thread (0x000001881a27d800):  JavaThread "Thread-16"
>   [_thread_in_native, id=5508,
>   stack(0x0000004a95900000,0x0000004a95a00000)]
>
> siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000019d6c1a8
>
> Registers: RAX=0x0000000019d6c1a8, RBX=0x0000004a959feeb0,
>   RCX=0x00007ffb7f5fab84, RDX=0x0000000000000000 RSP=0x0000004a959fee40,
>   RBP=0x0000004a959fefc0, RSI=0x000001881a27da50, RDI=0x00000000000008dc
>   R8 =0x0000004a959fed38, R9 =0x0000004a959fee30,
>   R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000246 R12=0x0000004a959ff070,
>   R13=0x000001881a614090, R14=0x0000004a959fef70, R15=0x000001881a27d800
>   RIP=0x000000007110b5db, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202
>
> Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000004a959fee40) 0x0000004a959fee40:
>   0000004a959fee68 0000000000000000 0x0000004a959fee50:
>   000000007110b230 0000004a959fef70 0x0000004a959fee60:
>   000001881a614090 0000000000000004 0x0000004a959fee70:
>   000001881a27da50 00000000000008dc 0x0000004a959fee80:
>   0000004a959fefc0 0000000071112590 0x0000004a959fee90:
>   000001881a27d800 0000004a959fef70 0x0000004a959feea0:
>   000001881a614090 000001881a27da50 0x0000004a959feeb0:
>   0000004a959ff070 00000000000008dc 0x0000004a959feec0:
>   0000004a959fefc0 0000000063358d94 0x0000004a959feed0:
>   000001881a614090 0000000000000000 0x0000004a959feee0:
>   0000000071113500 0000000071113be8 0x0000004a959feef0:
>   0000004a959fef20 0000000071112641 0x0000004a959fef00:
>   0000004a959fee90 0000000040000000 0x0000004a959fef10:
>   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x0000004a959fef20:
>   0000004a959fefc0 0000000071101595 0x0000004a959fef30:
>   000000000000001c 000001881a27da50
>
> Instructions: (pc=0x000000007110b5db) 0x000000007110b5bb:   c5 0f 1f
>   40 00 55 57 56 53 48 83 ec 28 48 8b 05 0x000000007110b5cb:   39 33 01
>   00 48 89 cb 48 85 c0 0f 84 c5 00 00 00 0x000000007110b5db:   8b 38 85
>   ff 0f 88 ab 00 00 00 48 8b 05 1c 33 01 0x000000007110b5eb:   00 48 85
>   c0 0f 84 bc 00 00 00 8b 30 85 f6 74 57
>
> Register to memory mapping:
>
> RAX=0x0000000019d6c1a8 is an unknown value RBX=0x0000004a959feeb0 is
>   pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001881a27d800
>   RCX=0x00007ffb7f5fab84 is an unknown value RDX=0x0000000000000000 is
>   an unknown value RSP=0x0000004a959fee40 is pointing into the stack for
>   thread: 0x000001881a27d800 RBP=0x0000004a959fefc0 is pointing into the
>   stack for thread: 0x000001881a27d800 RSI=0x000001881a27da50 is an
>   unknown value RDI=0x00000000000008dc is an unknown value R8
>   =0x0000004a959fed38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001881a27d800 R9 =0x0000004a959fee30 is pointing into the stack
>   for thread: 0x000001881a27d800 R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown
>   value R11=0x0000000000000246 is an unknown value
>   R12=0x0000004a959ff070 is pointing into the stack for thread:
>   0x000001881a27d800 R13=0x000001881a614090 is an unknown value
>   R14=0x0000004a959fef70 is pointing into the stack for thread:
>   0x000001881a27d800 R15=0x000001881a27d800 is a thread
>
> Stack: [0x0000004a95900000,0x0000004a95a00000], 
>   sp=0x0000004a959fee40,  free space=1019k Native frames: (J=compiled
>   Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C 
>   0x000000007110b5db C  0x0000000071112590 C  0x0000000071101595 C 
>   0x00000188023a9c6e
>
> Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j 
>   jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J+0 j 
>   jssc.SerialPort.openPort()Z+65 j 
>   scheduling.services.communication.Communication$2.call()Lscheduling/services/communication/Communication$ConnectionState;+98
>   j 
>   scheduling.services.communication.Communication$2.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
>   j  javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+26 j 
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42 j 
>   java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Answer (score -2):

try to start your app from command line,it will shows errors like jar

Comment: tested, comand pompt is empty just starting app, maby i should add some kind parameters?